# Usar call apenas em arquivos de lotes que contenham expressões de outro arquivo

Tags: windows, cmd

Tenho um diretório com arquivos *.bat* nomeados de forma aleatória, dentro de cada arquivo .bat deste diretório tenho nomes únicos como:

- nome1
- nome2
- nome3
- ...

Tenho também, dentro do mesmo diretório, um arquivo *apenas.txt*. Neste arquivo, cada linha é um nome dos que estão dentro dos arquivos com a extensão .bat.

Preciso de um comando para ser executado através de um arquivo de lotes do Windows que verifique cada uma das linhas do *apenas.txt* e execute um call no arquivo .bat que tenha este nome.

Exemplo prático:

Código do arquivo abc.bat

```
echo nome10
```

Código do arquivo xyz.bat

```
echo nome1
```

Texto no arquivo apenas.bat:

```
nome1
```

O que precisa ser executado pelo novo arquivo em lotes: call xyz.bat

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso:

```
set "File2Read=falhou.txt"
set "File3Read=call.txt"
If Not Exist "%File2Read%" (Goto :Error)
rem This will read a file into an array of variables and populate it 
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Type "%File2Read%"') do (
    set /a count+=1
    set "Line[!count!]=%%a"
)
rem Display array elements
For /L %%f in (1,1,%Count%) do (
    FOR %%G IN (*.bat) do (findstr /m "!Line[%%f]!" "%%G")>>call.txt
)

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Type "%File3Read%"') do (
    set /a count+=1
    set "Line[!count!]=%%a"
)
rem Display array elements
For /L %%c in (1,1,%Count%) do (
    call "!Line[%%c]!"
)

pause
Exit
::***************************************************
:Error
cls & Color 4C
echo(
echo   The file "%File2Read%" dos not exist !
Pause>nul
exit /b
::***************************************************
```

Baseado nesta resposta https://stackoverflow.com/a/41926276/5429657

Modifiquei da seguinte forma, o arquivo em lotes verifica os nomes dentro do arquivo *falhou.txt*, armazena o resultado da busca num arquivo *call.txt* aplica o call nos arquivos dentro do call.txt.

Comment: sua proposta funciona, mas é extremamente lenta, toda vez ele varre todos os arquivos .bat do diretório em busca do conteúdo no arquivo .txt, trabalho com mais ou menos 10 mil arquivos .bat neste diretório, então ficar esperando achar todos os nomes, é mais rápido encontrar manual =\

Comment: @talnun desculpe, não tenho conhecimento suficiente para melhorar este código