# É possível optimizar este código?

Tags: windows, for, cmd, batch

Fiz uma pergunta [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/309759/90997) e me enviaram uma [sugestão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/309925/90997) de um código que faz uma busca no conteúdo de todos arquivos .bat em um diretório utilizando como critério, nomes que estão em um arquivo .txt.

```
set "File2Read=falhou.txt"
set "File3Read=call.txt"
If Not Exist "%File2Read%" (Goto :Error)
rem This will read a file into an array of variables and populate it 
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Type "%File2Read%"') do (
    set /a count+=1
    set "Line[!count!]=%%a"
)
rem Display array elements
For /L %%f in (1,1,%Count%) do (
    FOR %%G IN (*.bat) do (findstr /m "!Line[%%f]!" "%%G")>>call.txt
)

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Type "%File3Read%"') do (
    set /a count+=1
    set "Line[!count!]=%%a"
)
rem Display array elements
For /L %%c in (1,1,%Count%) do (
    call "!Line[%%c]!"
)

pause
Exit
::***************************************************
:Error
cls & Color 4C
echo(
echo   The file "%File2Read%" dos not exist !
Pause>nul
exit /b
::***************************************************
```

O código funciona, o problema é que ele faz uma busca muito demorada, pois tenho 10 mil arquivos .bat a serem varridos em busca de cada um dos nomes, todas as vezes que um nome encontrado a busca recomeça do primeiro arquivo.

Seria possível melhorar isso de alguma forma?

Comment: Isto é um *script*, por que precisa otimizar?

Comment: @Maniero ele está demorando cerca de 4 horas para encontrar 20 nomes dentre os 10 mil arquivos, seria mais rápido fazer uma busca manual com o Notepad ++

Comment: A otimização é usar uma linguagem de programação feita para ser otimizada e não fazer um *script* de linha de comando.

Comment: @talnun Você precisa saber qual arquivo contém o nome buscado? Uma ideia é, antes da busca, criar um arquivo temporário com o conteúdo de todos os arquivos e fazer a busca dentro deste arquivo temporário.

Comment: @Dherik isso poderia gerar problemas com arquivos gigantes e pouco espaço em disco, mas essa preocupação não se aplica (provavelmente) a este caso

Comment: exatamente @Dherik, pretendo buscar no conteúdo de diversos arquivos, nomes únicos, o problema é que o script acima volta a varrer todos os arquivos quando encontra o primeiro nome, o segundo, assim por diante...

Comment: @talnun, sua dificuldade é ter uma ideia do quê fazer ou em como fazer? A ideia que eu dei não é útil para você?

Comment: a dificuldade é de como fazer @Dherik, eu vou estou tentando da seguinte forma: criei um arquivo .txt apenas com os 10 mil nomes, que são únicos, na mesma ordem que os arquivos .bat estão nomeados, então o nome50 está na linha 50 desse .txt, fulano100 está na linha 100 do .txt, estou em busca de como saber a linha correspondente ao nome e assim "concatenar" a função call para chama-lo... mais alguns dias pesquisando e devo conseguir